# Adding more layers to tensorflow MNIST tutorial makes accuracy drop and sometimes accuracy remains constant over iteration for batch

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, computer-vision

i was checking this tutorial for deep learning ,he made a simply nueral network with one hidden layer. i did same and it was working fine(accuracy 94%) ,now i added one more layer and its accuracy got decreaed to (10%) i dont know why? 
Below is my code

```
`import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
mnist  = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/",one_hot=True)

input_images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,784])
target_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,10])

hidden_nodes1 = 512
hidden_nodes2 = 256

    input_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([784,hidden_nodes1]))
    input_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden_nodes1]))


    hidden_weights1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_nodes1,hidden_nodes2]))
    hidden_biases1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden_nodes2]))

    hidden_weights2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_nodes2,10]))
    hidden_biases2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))


    input_layer = tf.matmul(input_images,input_weights)
    hidden_layer1 = tf.nn.relu(input_layer + input_biases)

    hidden_layer2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden_layer1,hidden_weights1) + hidden_biases1)


    digits_weights = tf.matmul(hidden_layer2,hidden_weights2)+hidden_biases2



    loss_funtion = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=digits_weights,labels=target_labels))

    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.2).minimize(loss_funtion)

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(digits_weights,1),tf.argmax(target_labels,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    for x in range(2000):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        optimizer.run(feed_dict={input_images:batch[0],target_labels:batch[1]})
        if ((x+1)%100==0):
            print("Training Epoc"+str(x+1))
            print("Accuracy"+str(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={input_images:mnist.test.images,target_labels:mnist.test.labels})))`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually fine. But, by adding a new hidden layer with `256` nodes, you are dramatically increasing the number of learnable parameters! Your model architecture, essentially, has become too big. This is what I propose, you can reduce the number of nodes from `512` and `256` to something like `128` or max `256` for both. Then, use a much lower value for the learning rate as the current learning rate is too high and may not converge on a minima properly (or may even diverge). So, I'd change it to something like `0.01` or even lower instead. Another thing you could try is to use the `AdamOptimizer` instead of the `GradientDescentOptimizer`. Try these and the code should work fine!